# How to prove this measure is $\sigma$-finite? Donald Cohn Measure Theory exercise 4.2.2

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\{r_{n}\}$ be an enumeration of the rational numbers, and for each positive integer $n$ let $f_{n}: \mathbb{R} \xrightarrow{} \mathbb{R}$ be a nonnegative Borel function that satisfies $\int f_{n} d\lambda = 1$ and vanishes outside the closed interval of length $1/2^{n}$ centered at $r_{n}$. Define $\mu$ on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ by $\mu (A) = \int_{A} \sum_{n}f_{n} d \lambda$.

In part (a) it asks to show $\sum_{n}f_{n}(x) < \infty$ holds $\lambda$-a.e., which can be done by Borel-Cantelli Lemma, considering each interval $I_{n}$ centered at $r_{n}$.

My question is as in part (b), how to show $\mu$ is sigma-finite. It says in part (b) that each nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has infinite measure under $\mu$, which I haven't shown but is quite intuitive, because each open interval contains infinitely many $I_{n}$'s.

So the usual way of considering an increasing sequence of intervals fails, and how should I find the sequence of subsets to show $\mu$ is sigma-finite?

Comment: What about $\left\{x\in\mathbb R\mid\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}f_n(x)\le k\right\}\cap[-k,k]$, for $k\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: @Will I see so that's the purpose of part (a). Thank you!